# How do I load these LINQ results into my ViewModel class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have a LINQ query which returns results that match up with my `PictureGallery` class. I need to load them into my `ViewModel` but im getting the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I'm rather new at C#. How do I cast "Results" into my "PictureGallery" viewmddel class?

Thanks in advance!

Controller:

```
//Test MediaID
var MediaID = 75;

//Query Results
var Results = from g in DB.Galleries
              join m in DB.Media on g.GalleryID equals m.GalleryID
              where g.GalleryID == GalleryID
              orderby m.MediaDate descending, m.MediaID descending
              select new { g.GalleryTitle, Media = m };

//Create my viewmodel
var Model = new GalleryViewModel
{
    MediaID = MediaID,
    PictureGallery = Results, //This line throws the error.
    PictureCount = Results.Count()
};
```

ViewModels:

```
public class GalleryViewModel
{
    public int? MediaID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PictureGallery> PictureGallery { get; set; }
    public int PictureCount { get; set; }
}

public class PictureGallery
{
    public int GalleryID { get; set; }
    public string GalleryTitle { get; set; }
    public int MediaID { get; set; }
    public string MediaTitle { get; set; }
    public string MediaDesc { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rephrase your query as:

```
//Query Results
var Results = from g in DB.Galleries
              join m in DB.Media on g.GalleryID equals m.GalleryID
              where g.GalleryID == GalleryID
              orderby m.MediaDate descending, m.MediaID descending
              select new PictureGallery {
                                GalleryID = g.GalleryId,
                                GalleryTitle = g.GalleryTitle,
                                MediaID = m.MediaID,
                                MediaTitle = m.MediaTitle,
                                MediaDesc = m.MediaDesc,
                                Rating = m.Rating,
                                Views = m.Views} ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set an `IEnumerable<PictureGallery>` to an `IQueryable<anonymous>`. You need to transform to the correct type:

```
var Model = new GalleryViewModel
{
    MediaID = MediaID,
    PictureGallery = Results
        .Select(r => new PictureGallery {
            GalleryID = r.Media.GalleryID,
            GalleryTitle = r.GalleryTitle,
            MediaID = r.Media.MediaID,
            ... // and so on
        }),
    PictureCount = Results.Count()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Then You can write
 var list = result.ToList();

Then pass it to view like this
return View(list);

You can accept it in your view like this
@model List

Where ViewModel is a simple class with properties to accept the resultant values after query execution.

You can check these attachments[Linq query,View Model,View[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4f4y.jpg)[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4f4y.jpg)